# Master and slave Bind DNS Ubuntu server

Tags: domains, domain-name-system, ubuntu

I have two Ubuntu 12.04LTS servers on different locations:

```
ns1.vidrih.info points to master DNS server with IP 93.103.164.154 and
ns2.vidrih.info points to slave DNS server with IP 46.150.36.23
```

named.conf.local include for domain is:

```
zone "vidrih.info" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/vidrih.info.hosts";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
};
```

My zone file is:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400
vidrih.info             IN SOA  ns1.vidrih.info. nejc.vidrih.gmail.com. (
                                2013042201 ; serial
                                3600       ; refrenski
                                1800       ; retry
                                604800     ; expire
                                86400      ; minimum
                                )
    NS    ns1.vidrih.info.
    NS    ns2.vidrih.info.
    A    93.103.164.154
```

I get an error on http://dnscheck.pingdom.com:

> Name server ns1.vidrih.info does not answer queries over TCP or UDP.

syslog looks fine: server named[3871]: zone vidrih.info/IN: loaded serial 2013042201
Port 53 is opened.

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: What address(es) is port 53 bound to, iptables, firewall for your network? If that domain is new, the serial should be YYYYMMDD00.

Comment: The domain is not new (it is a few years old), server is behind router with firewall, port 53 is forwarded. I dont't think the problem is in the network, becuase untill now server on ns1 location was my only dns server and it worked fine.

Comment: The serial is used to inform the slave that the zone has been updated, but that isn't your primary problem. What does the `listen:` stanza state in your `named.conf`?

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the serial. I don't have any listen: in named.conf(.options).

Comment: Hmmm, what do you get if you type `netstat -pan | grep :53` ?

Comment: tcp        0      0 192.168.0.150:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3010/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3010/named      
udp        0      0 192.168.0.150:53        0.0.0.0:*                           3010/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           3010/named

Comment: That's correct. So, you're forwarding 93.103.164.154 to 192.168.0.150?

Comment: Yes, I have many other ports forwarded and they work just fine.

Comment: So, can you post your named.conf? I have a feeling you're not replying to any requests due to the configuration...

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/cEeGFWDc

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, you need to add a line like this to your named.conf

`listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.150; };`

As the default setting for bind 9+ is to listen by default only on 127.0.0.1.